# EntityType has no key defined, despite using [Key]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I am configuring context in my application. These are throwing expection:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

It looks like this:

```
BookList.Models.Book: : EntityType 'Book' has no key defined. Define the key      for this EntityType.
Books: EntityType: EntitySet 'Books' is based on type 'Book' that has no keys defined.
```

My Book class looks like this:

```
public class Book
{
    [Display(Name = "Id:")]
    [Key]
    private int BookId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title:")]
    [MaxLength(35)]
    [Required]
    private string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description:")]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    private string Description { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, there's `[Key]` annotation. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your BookId property private? Try set this property as public.

Comment: That was the reason. Thanks for help.

Comment: See my updated anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything must be given to EntityFramework when use reflection to detect  PropertyInfo instances, only use those that are public.You just need to set BookId property as public:

```
public class Book
{
    [Display(Name = "Id:")]
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title:")]
    [MaxLength(35)]
    [Required]
    private string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description:")]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    private string Description { get; set; }
}
```